# For AngularJS Custom Directives, what is a correct way to find sub-elements in your template?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Say, if you define a directive with the template:

```
<div>
    <button id="add-button">add</button>
    {{ value }}
    <button id="minus-button">minus</button>
</div>
```

Then what is a correct way to find your button in your `link(scope, element, attrs)` function?

---

Some thoughts and details:

I have seen

```
angular.element(document.getElementById("add-button"))
```

(the `angular.element` is just to convert it back to a jqLite/jQuery object)

but what if a user adds your directives multiple times on their page, then that line will find the wrong element because `document.getElementById("add-button")` will probably find the first matching element on the whole page with that ID.

Since [jqLite](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) can only find by tag name, so we may be able to do, by going back to DOM methods:

```
angular.element(element[0].querySelector("#add-button"))
```

Or, I don't know why jqLite doesn't let you find by class name or by ID, so it may be recommended to actually load jQuery before AngularJS, and use the full version of jQuery:

```
element.find("#add-button")
```

**Or, supposedly only one element with the same ID should exist on the whole page, so to be more correct, we really should use class name instead of ID to identify the element**, such as `<button class="add-button">` and find it by

```
element.find(".add-button")
```

I think searching by tag name and then using the 1st found element or 2nd found element is not such a good way, because what if the template is changed or rearranged later, then you need to change your code too, so it is too tightly coupled together.

Comment: Question is: why do you need to find any element in your directive? Can't it be handled with another directive?

Comment: will there be circumstances? Or can most of them be handled by `ng-click`, or other customer directives?  I see Angular code sample looking for sub-elements and adding event handlers to them, or finding the status line for later change of content... could it be just done by `scope.status` and `{{ status }}`?

Comment: the example I saw get the sub-element, so then google map can be instantiated on it later on... so I think it is a third party library situation

Comment: The usual way I handle those situation is having extra directive which requires `^topDirective`. In link function, i register the element using topDirective controller and I am all happy to go.

Answer (score 1):

The most common way (seen by John Papa and Todd Motto) is to go with jqLite.
The worst way is using JQuery inside directives without restrictions.

Absolutly worst case:

```
$('.some-class')
```

Much better:

```
element.find('.some-class')
```

Also seen and valid:

```
$(element.find('.some-class'))
```

So, why you gonna do such things, manipulating DOM from a directive? There are a whole bunch of reasons. Maybe you want to initialize some JQuery plugins like datepicker or nanoscroller, then you need such things.

Styleguides are just philosphy, you can accept them, you just believe in small parts of the whole guide or you create your own. There are some guidelines out there, which can improve your code heavily (performance, readablity, etc.).

**Styleguides**

[Angular 2 John Papa](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide)

[Angular 1.x John Papa](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md)

[Angular 1.x Todd Motto](https://github.com/toddmotto/angular-styleguide)

Comment: `element.find('.some-class')` won't work if it is just jqLite, i think

Comment: @CodeNashor - jqLite limits find method on element to tags only. Class search won't work. If it works for you it means you have full jQuery object.

Comment: Do you have any proof of this? Also in documentation and other stackoverflow posts, there are jqLite class selectors. And I think my jqLite objects are jqLite objects, because I cant fire all functions of jQuery on it.

Comment: @CodeNashor if you don't load jQuery, then you will find that you can only find by tag names.  Documentation is at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element  `"find() - Limited to lookups by tag name"`